# What is the fatest way of calculating summary statistics in SQL when comparing these two queries?

Tags: sql

I have a table on PostgreSQL having the columns: `date`, `col1`, `condition`. I would like to calculate the statistical summary of `col1` segmenting by `date` and `condition`. To this end, I wrote the following query

```
SELECT date
      ,col1
      ,condition
      ,COUNT(*)
      ,SUM(col1)
      ,MAX(col1)
      ,MIN(col1)
      ,AVG(col1)
      ,STDDEV(col1)
      ,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) AS "Q3"
      ,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) AS "Median"
      ,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) AS "Q1"
FROM table
GROUP BY date, condition
```

I could also write the same query as

```
    SELECT date
      ,col1
      ,condition
      ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY date, condition)
      ,SUM(col1) OVER(PARTITION BY date, condition)
      ,MAX(col1) OVER(PARTITION BY date, condition)
      ,MIN(col1) OVER(PARTITION BY date, condition)
      ,AVG(col1) OVER(PARTITION BY date, condition)
      ,STDDEV(col1) OVER(PARTITION BY date, condition)
      ,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) OVER (PARTITION BY date, condition) AS "Q3"
      ,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) OVER (PARTITION BY date, condition) AS "Median"
      ,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) OVER (PARTITION BY date, condition) AS "Q1"
FROM table
GROUP BY date, condition
```

Which one of these queries would be the fastest? For my own (brief) experience, the second seems faster. However, running the clause `OVER(PARTITION BY date, condition)` should slow it?

I have not a good knowledge of SQL and an explanation would help to me to write the queries more efficiently.

Comment: Most explanation of what YOU mean by "statistical summary" would help.

Comment: Done it. It is in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want something like this?

```
select date, condition, avg(col1), min(col1), max(col1)
from t
group by date, condition;
```

Comment: I would like to add also the percentiles